# Equivalence of Kaplan-Meier estimator and EM algorithm

Tags: survival, nonparametric, censoring, kaplan-meier

For right-censored failure time data, in a non-parametric setting, is there an equivalence between using the EM algorithm (i.e. calculating the expected log-likelihood and maximizing) and the Kaplan-Meier estimator? Any references or explanation are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

BW Turnbull - ‎1976 paper: The empirical distribution function with arbitrarily grouped, censored and truncated data